# Expand textarea outside parent td

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea, expand

I have a table where I would like to be able to double-click on cells to edit them. Even though I am only showing the first few characters in the actual table  cell I would like to show/edit the full text on double click inside a textarea element.

The textarea element would stay hidden until the table cell is doubleclicked, it then becomes visible on top of the table cell until blur() event when it's hidden again. If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know.

```js
$(function () {
    $('td.nota').dblclick(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();      //stop the propagation of the event here
       $(this).children().css("display","block");
       $(this).children().focus();
       //alert('test');
    });
});

$('td.nota').children().blur(function(){
$(this).css("display","none");
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 50px 25px;
}

table {
  width: auto !important;
}

.edit-box {
display:none;
float: left;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: -28px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="761">
            </td>
            <td class="text-left nota" id="761" style="max-width: 20ch;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<textarea class="edit-box" rows="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</textarea></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="760">
            </td>
            <td class="text-left nota" id="760" style="max-width: 20ch;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<textarea class="edit-box" rows="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</textarea></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Same code in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prxbl/1hw2f0b9/29/

Current problems:

1. Textarea element should expand beyond the parent td, on top of everything, without breaking table layout.
2. Textarea element should not be transparent, it should mask elements behind.

Any help on solving these problems is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to contain the answer.  That defeats the purpose of the question for future visitors, and is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problem 1 and 2 can be solved by adding "position: absolute;" to class .edit-box in CSS. Now the textarea element can expand outside of parent container.